# VB.Net Flags Public Enum SnapshotFlags - Constant expression not representable in type 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net

Little bit stuck been trying for ages to get a bit of code to work and this little snippet is stopping me from doing the rest can anyone help

```
<Flags>
Public Enum SnapshotFlags
    HeapList = 1
    Process = 2
    Thread = 4
    [Module] = 8
    Module32 = 16
    All = 31
    Inherit = 2147483648
End Enum
```

[Error That is shown in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKGOC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Integer datatype has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647, so your `Inherit = 2147483648` exceeds that.

Simple solution would be to change the Enum's base type to Long:

```
<Flags>
Public Enum SnapshotFlags As Long
    HeapList = 1
    Process = 2
    Thread = 4
    [Module] = 8
    Module32 = 16
    All = 31
    Inherit = 2147483648
End Enum
```

In this specific case, using UInteger would also work.

Another solution would be to use -2147483648 instead of 2147483648 as the flag value.